# Is it possible to write to many places atomically using only compare-and-swap?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, atomic, compare-and-swap

#### Question

Given atomic `compare-and-swap` as a primitive, is it possible to write to many different memory places atomically? That is, for example:

```
// initialization
mem[0] = 0;
mem[1] = 0;

// thread A runs
mem[0] = 1;
mem[1] = 1;

// thread B runs
int x = mem[0];
int y = mem[1];
printf("%d %d", x, y);
```

Here, thread B may output `0, 0`, if it runs before A, `1, 1`, if it runs after A, and `1, 0`, if it runs between the two statements of A. I want to avoid the `1, 0` case by atomically writing `mem[0] = 1` and `mem[1] = 1`.

#### What I've tried

I could obviously have a semaphore to lock indices 0,1 on this very specific use case, but

1. it requires extra memory,
2. it doesn't allow me to write to an arbitrary number of indices.

I wonder if the effect could be achieved without extra memory.

Comment: No, `CAS` is only atomic on one memory location at a time.

Comment: For anything more you need a mutex.

Comment: The question would me much more interesting, if there were actual problem here... "to save memory" is not a real one, sine a mutex is typically just a few bytes or few tens of bytes in size.

Comment: @NominalAnimal the problem is writing to many places in memory without another thread reading a partially updated view of the sequence. I don't know how to do that. It seems like you have some obvious idea in mind but I actually don't know.

Comment: There are many approaches, but they all depend on details not discussed. For example, is there only one writer, or one reader, or are there multiple writers and readers? How often do the writes occur compared to reads? What is the true reason for preferring lockless operation: minimum writer latency? updates done from a signal handler? The one I suspect might be relevant to you involves duplicating the data, and using three generation counters. With proper barriers, that allows readers to get complete "old" or "new" view, even during an update.. but that uses 2× the memory.